# Should I write OCJP 16 or 1.7?

Tags: java, scjp

I am planning to give my OCJP certification exam. But i am confused whether to write 1.6 or 1.7?
To be specific , I want to know what are the drawbacks or disadvantages if I write OCJP 1.6 version exam?

Answer (score 2):

For OCJP 6 you need to take this exam "Oracle Certified Professional, Java SE 6 Programmer"

but for OCJP 7 you need to take two exam "Oracle Certified Associate, Java SE 7 Programmer"
 and "Oracle Certified Professional, Java SE 7 Programmer"

The only difference is "Building Database Applications with JDBC" otherwise all of topics are same. In OCJP7 they are seprated in two exams but in OCJP6 they are included in one then you will pay for one exam.